# Как одним процессом писать в поток входных данных другого процесса(Или как узнать дескриптор потока вывода прцесса)

Tags: c++, linux, c, потоки-данных, posix

Пусть есть скомпилированная программа PR1, на языке с++, код которой выглядит так(Но этот код нам неизвестен, имеем только готовый бинарник):

```
     #include <iostream>

     using namespace std;

     int main(){
         string pass = "qwe123";
         string buf;
         while(buf != pass){
              cin >> buf ;
         }
         cout << "\ndone";

         return 0;
     }
```

Пусть мы не знаем, что с++ хранит строки внутри бинарника в том виде, в котором они есть и не знаем ничего про реверс инжиниринг. Мы хотим написать программу на с++, которая будет угадывать пароль(пусть просто перебором подставлять туда все комбинации символов, пока в поток выходных данных процесса запущенной программы PR1 не попадет слово done) внутри программы PR1, как и где получить дескриптор потока входных данных программы PR1 на этапе её исполнения?

PS пусть ос Linux, думаю это важно
PSS Правильно ли я понимаю, что у каждого процесса свои дескрипторы потока ввода/вывода?

Comment: @Mike спасибо, выглядит логично, постараюсь реализовать, потом дам знать о результатах!

Comment: @Mike - Ваши два комментария-в чистом виде ответ, может, так и оформите его? Я бы за такой проголосовал!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дескрипторы у каждого процесса одинаковые. 0 - stdin, 1 - stdout, 2 - stderr.

Вам надо в своем процессе, который будет подбирать пароли:

- подготовить 2 pipe для связи с другим процессом
- породить дочерний процесс с помощью fork()
- в полученном дочернем процессе с помощью dup2() переназначить ввод вывод со стандартных дескрипторов на свои pipe
- в нем же запустить вместо себя (exec()) требуемую программу

Часто этот процесс называют popen2, [пример функции](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-popen2-implementation)

Второй вариант, выполнить то же самое с помощью shell, подготовить именованный pipe, который будет читать ваша программа, запустить свою программу с перенаправлением ее вывода на стандартный ввод испытуемой программы, при этом перенаправив ее вывод в pipe, который читает ваша программа. Выходит что то вроде: `ваша_программа | целевая_программа >>fifo_file`

Comment: Я думаю, что фраза `на этапе её исполнения` означает, что целевой процесс уже запущен и требуется подключиться к его потокам. Тогда, наверное, fork не будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Дескриптор процесса можно получить в `/proc/${pid}/fd/0,1,2`

Например запускаю в одном терминале cat, во втором

```
echo hello > /proc/574679/fd/0
```

и вижу hello на первом.

Получить ответ обратно сложнее, ведь терминал вычитывает дескриптор. Понадобится gdb чтоб открыть новый дескриптор - метод описан тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/2101808 и какая-то интересная програмка в другом ответе https://stackoverflow.com/a/26363421/2101808

Comment: Дело в том, что тогда программа, принимающая пароль на вход почему-то его не считывает внутрь, хотя программа подбирающая пароль печатает их и печатает символ перевода на новую строку, что должно быть сигналом запароленной программы. Может я что-то не то делаю?

Comment: пароль может вводиться не со стандартного ввода, а захватом клавиатуры

Comment: А что это значит и где об этом почитать?

Comment: Почитать можно strace процесса. Но это длинная портянка. Где почитать про безопасный ввод пароля не подскажу. Но например ssh тоже не принимает стандартный ввод. Надо через pts/pty в этом случае